# Linux security implications for sudo, su to service account & add secondary group to admin Tomcat?

Tags: linux, security

I have a named account to login to a Linux host.  Tomcat is running under a Service Account named "tomcat"

I periodically need to do admin functions like modify tomcat-users.xml
which is configured as

```
-rw-------. 1 tomcat tomcat   1671 Mar 25 20:50 tomcat-users.xml
```

I want to audit changes.  Should I

- Give named users sudo with entitlements to edit file
- Give named users entitlement to su to the tomcat account and make any needed changes (either via sudo or giving admins the tomcat password)
- Add permissions to allow members of the tomcat group to edit the file and add tomcat as a secondary group to named users.

using sudo would open up potential config errors that would give named users more access than I intended and would allow them to use sudo -i and bypass auditing.  Changing the file permissions expands who can read the file seems risky.

I'm really looking for risks & advantages/disadvantages I have not covered above to help decide the approach to take and not just opinions and "I do it this way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only working way to have an audit trail you can trust is to work with a least privilege policy, i.e., deny access by default.

If you go with `sudo` access, you can certainly limit what users can and can't do; but you also need to be aware of the caveats that might apply.

In this case, you requirement is to grant access to a group of users to edit a specific file.

Best practices dictate that each user has a personal account. 
It's not required to make those users belong to any group, as this is covered by `sudo` already.

Assuming your users belong to the `operators` group, a `sudorule` would look like:

```
Cmnd_Alias TOMCAT_COMMANDS = sudoedit /path/to/tomcat-users.xml
Host_Alias TOMCAT_HOSTS = foo.example.com, bar.example.com

Defaults log_host
Defaults log_output
Defaults syslog_badpri=alert
Defaults syslog_goodpri=notice
Defaults:%operators editor=/usr/bin/rvim

%operators TOMCAT_HOSTS = (tomcat)PASSWD: TOMCAT_COMMANDS
```

This ensures they can't scape the editor, as they are forced to use `rvim`, and provides some sane defaults to log their activities. You can further harden the `sudo` policy, and you can add more functionality to it. This is an example.

Another way to accomplish something similar is to version control changes to that file, and have it managed using a configuration management system.

RBAC to these kind of systems is a broad topic, as it is auditing.
It's up to you to collect and analyse the logs generated.